# How can I serve a Django application using the SPDY protocol?

Tags: django, hosting, spdy

What is the best way to serve a Django application over the SPDY [1] protocol?

[1] http://www.chromium.org/spdy

Comment: An add-on to this question - making it work for CPython

Comment: Is there a way to do it with Apache by combining `mod_wsgi` and `mod_spdy` ?

Comment: As of now, I believe there isn't. At least after reading a lot of stuff about these two. There is some way of translating to HTTP, but don't know exactly what can one gain from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with nginx > 1.5.10 and Django run as fastcgi server.

Recent versions of Chrome and Firefox [dropped support for SPDY v2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY#cite_note-Fx28beta-23). So you need at least SPDY3 support on the server side. [Nginx versions higher than 1.5.10](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html) support version 3 of the protocol.

**Django Mainline Installation**

Currently (as of Feb 2014) Nginx > 1.5.10 is only available from the mainline branch, not from stable. On most Linux distributions, it is easiest to install [mainline packages provided by the nginx project](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#mainline).

**Nginx and Django configuration**

The Django documentation explains how to run [Django with Nginx through fastcgi](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx). The configuration that is provided there can be used as a starting point.

In addition, you need SSL certificates for your host and extend the Nginx configuration in the following ways:

- The listen configuration options needs to be modified to:
  from `listen 80;` to `listen 443 ssl spdy;`.
- You need to add basic ssl configuration options, most importantly a certificate and key.

So, both modifications combined, the configuration may look as follows:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl spdy;
    server_name  yourhost.example.com;

    ssl_certificate      <yourhostscertificate>.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  <yourhostskey>.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Then run your Django as in fastcgi mode, as follows:

```
python ./manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080
```

**Testing your setup**

- Point your browser to https://yourhost.example.com
- You should be able to verify that the connection is done via SPDY in:

  - Chrome: Look for an active SPDY session in `chrome://net-internals/#spdy`
  - Firefox: Check the Firebug Network tab and look for the `X-Firefox-Spdy:"3.1"` response header.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to run Django on Jython with Jetty - http://www.evonove.it/blog/en/2012/12/28/django-jetty-spdy-blazing-fast/

Also, apparently nginx has some [draft module](http://nginx.org/patches/spdy/README.txt) for SPDY